# How to infer schema of serialized JSON column in Spark SQL?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table where there is 1 column which is serialized JSON. I want to apply schema inference on this JSON column. I don't know schema to pass as input for JSON extraction (e.g: from_json function).

I can do this in Scala like

```
val contextSchema = spark.read.json(data.select("context").as[String]).schema
val updatedData = data.withColumn("context", from_json(col("context"), contextSchema))
```

How can I transform this solution to a pure Spark-SQL?

Answer (score 2):

For `spark-sql` use **`toDDL`** to generate schema then use the schema in **`from_json`**.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show(10,false)
//+---+-------------------+
//|seq|json               |
//+---+-------------------+
//|1  |{"id":1,"name":"a"}|
//+---+-------------------+

val sch=spark.read.json(df.select("json").as[String]).schema.toDDL
//sch: String = `id` BIGINT,`name` STRING

df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")

spark.sql(s"""select seq,jsn.* from (select *,from_json(json,"$sch") as jsn  from tmp)""").
show(10,false)
//+---+---+----+
//|seq|id |name|
//+---+---+----+
//|1  |1  |a   |
//+---+---+----+
```

Comment: I am looking for pure Spark-SQL solution. Environment where I want to apply this only supports Spark-SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [schema_of_json()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#schema_of_json) function to infer JSON schema.

```
select from_json(<column_name>, schema_of_json(<sample_JSON>)) from <table>
```

Comment: I don't have sample JSON. I am hoping it would be possible to get it table itself.

Comment: Is JSON structure/schema is fixed? In that case you can form schema and pass that to `from_json`

Comment: No. JSON structure/schema changes with input.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by

> 1. converting it to RDD and read with spark dataframe

```py
spark
  .read
  .option("inferSchema", True)
  .json(
      df.rdd.map(
          lambda rec: rec.context
      )
  )
```

> 2. if field/path is known beforehand, we can use

```py
df.select(json_tuple(col("context"),"<json path or attribute>").alias("field_name")).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("JsonInferSchema").getOrCreate()

data = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, '{"name":"John", "age":30}'),
    (2, '{"name":"Doe", "age":25}')
], ["id", "context"])

data.createOrReplaceTempView("tempTable")

query = """
SELECT 
    id, 
    context,
    get_json_object(context, '$.name') as name,
    get_json_object(context, '$.age') as age
FROM tempTable
"""

updatedData = spark.sql(query)

updatedData.show()
```